# A continuous random variable X has probability density function

Tags: probability

A continuous random variable X has probability density function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{x^{3}}&,x\geq1;\\0&,\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Find the value of $p\ (0<p<1)$ for which $E(X^p)=\frac{3}{2}$.

I tried to integrate $x^p  \frac{2}{x^3}$, but I got $p= -2/3$, which must be wrong. Can anyone please tell me the way of finding $p$?

Comment: Welcome! Please share your thoughts on the problem: Although many are willing to help with homework and similar problems, people aren't generally willing to simply do the problem for you. So please edit your question to include your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to carry a negative sign or something.

We have $$ \int_1^\infty x^p \frac{2}{x^3} \, \mathrm{d}x = - \frac{2}{p-2}, p<2 $$

Setting the result equal to $\frac{3}{2}$ yields $p=\frac{2}{3}$.